# Why would Simperium return an "unknown username" error?

Tags: simperium

I am trying to connect to the Simperium API using the Node simperium module. I created a SimpleNote account to use to store the notes, but I am getting an "unknown username" when I try to auth.authorize:

```
Failed to authenticate Error: unknown username: my-account@my-domain.com
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> 
(/path/to/my/project/node_modules/simperium/lib/simperium/auth.js:71:20)
```

I am presently logged into the account though, and copy/pasted the email address correctly. What might cause an unknown username error for a valid account?

My code is mostly ripped from the sample:

```
  var Client = Simperium.Client
  var Auth = Simperium.Auth

  var client = new Client( process.env.SIMPERIUM_APP_ID );

  var auth = new Auth( process.env.SIMPERIUM_APP_ID, process.env.SIMPERIUM_API_KEY );

  var interval = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, lastInt;

  client.connect();

  auth.on( 'authorize', function( user ) {
    var notes = client.bucket( 'note' );

    client.accessToken = user.access_token;
  } );

  auth.authorize(
    process.env.SIMPERIUM_EMAIL,
    process.env.SIMPERIUM_PASSWORD
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, the Simperium API username needs to be a *Simperium* account, not a SimpleNote account as the sample code suggests.

Comment: That's correct! Simplenote user accounts are actually Simperium user accounts for the Simplenote app. The user accounts which you will create in your own app are going to be entirely separate from those created in Simplenote.